# ruby one-liner from two hashes

Tags: ruby

```
a = {"rows" => [{"id" => "231-z", "name" => 'jon', "age"=> 27, "state" => 'AL'}, 
                {"id" => "4121-x", "name" => 'ton', "age"=> 37, "state" => 'VA'}
               ]
    }

b = {"rows" => [{"key" => ["xyz","4121-x"], "value" =>{"sum" => 12312, "realage" => 29}}, 
                {"key" => ["xyz","231-z"], "value" =>{"sum" => 1212, "realage" => 33}}
               ]
    }
```

In hash `a`, `age` is incorrect

In hash `b`, `realage` is correct. Also in hash `b` id is the second value in the first array that maps to `id` of hash `a` . Those are 4121-x, 231-z correspond to hash a

I want to correct the age in hash `a` and swap it with the `realage` of hash `b`
I can do it in multiple steps, but is it possible to do it in one liner or very short? So finally correct hash `a` should look like

```
a = {"rows" => [{"id" => "231-z", "name" => 'jon', "age"=> 33, "state" => 'AL'}, 
                {"id" => "4121-x", "name" => 'ton', "age"=> 29, "state" => 'VA'}
               ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this look reasonable?

```
a['rows'].each_with_index do |ah, i|
  (bh = b['rows'].select {|h| h['key'].last == ah['id'] }.first) &&
    a['rows'][i] = ah.update('age' => bh['value']['realage'])
end

p a

{
    "rows" => [
        [0] {
               "id" => "231-z",
             "name" => "jon",
              "age" => 33,
            "state" => "AL"
        },
        [1] {
               "id" => "4121-x",
             "name" => "ton",
              "age" => 29,
            "state" => "VA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note it will update `a` only if corresponding `id` found in `b`.

Also, the rows order does not matter, nor matter the rows number, it is only important `b` to have a row with same `id` as processed row in `a`

#### [Here is a Working Demo](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=ruby-one-liner-from-two-hashes.rb&run=true)

Comment: Thanks @silvu I have trimmed your code a bit http://cibox.org/jvkumar/test-repo?file=test-file&lang=ruby&run=true#

However it is 2 steps process, but much closer to what I am looking for.

Comment: @JVK, looks much better, just make sure to add an `&&` to make sure `a` is updated only if corresponding row found in `b`

Comment: @silvu Got the idea from yours, so you get the credit. Selected your answer. In fact, you answered my datamapper question yesterday too. Thanks to you for your help again.